# Exception Policy with DataBase Trace Listener in Enterprise Library 5.0 not logging exception into SQL database

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Enterprise library 5.0 with sharepoint to log exception into SQLdatabase.I use Windows 7 OS and Visual Studio 2010.

(1) As given in a link, I created 'Logging' database in SQLEXPRESS by running the script in the location  (C:\Documents and Settings\Venkatesan\My Documents\EntLib50Src\Blocks\Logging\Src\DatabaseTraceListener\Scripts\CreateLoggingDb)

(2) I Opened the web.config file in enterprise library (EntLib Config .Net 4) and mentioned the connection string for a database instance (ExampleDatabase) with connection string "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Logging.mdf;User Instance=true"

(3) I mentioned the exception policy(MyPolicy) ,exception type(All Exceptions) ,Database trace listener and so on.. and hence the web.config file is as follows:
i ve provided only the required portions in web.config file


  
    
    
    
..
  
  
    
      
    
    
      
    
    
      
        
          
        
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
  
  
    
      
        
          
            
              
            
          
        
      
    
  
  
  
    
  
..
    
      
..
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
..
      
..
(4) I deployed the required dlls in GAC and in web application's bin as well...
Previously, i had not deployed ent lib dlls in GAC,but i got an error mentioning i must deploy them in GAC.

(5) I Added the ent lib dlls as references in the solution project.

(6) My project code is as follows:

using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.SqlCe;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration;   using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration;

namespace MyEntLibProj.Layouts.MyEntLibProj
{
    public partial class MyApplicationPage : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("This is an error!!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception ex1;
                bool result = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "MyPolicy", out ex1);
                if (result)
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

When i debug the code, although I am not getting any exception and 'result' value is true, the ArgumentNull Exception is not getting logged into my database.Please help me in finding out where I would have been wrong...

Answer (score 0):

My web.config file:

< configuration>
  < configSections>
    <  section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings,

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,

PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    < section name="exceptionHandling" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,

PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    < section name="dataConfiguration"
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
.. 
  < loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true"    defaultCategory="General" >
    < listeners>
      < add name="Database Trace Listener"
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener,Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"       databaseInstanceName="ExampleDatabase" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"        addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter" />
    
    < formatters>
      < add      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}
Message: {message}{newline}
Category: 
{category}{newline}
Priority: {priority}{newline}
EventId: {eventid}{newline}
Severity:{severity}{newline}
Title:{title}{newline}
Machine: {localMachine}{newline}
App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}
ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}
Process Name: 
{localProcessName}{newline}
Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}
Win32 
ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}
Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter" /> 
    < categorySources>
      < add switchValue="All" name="General">
        < listeners>
          < add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        
      
    
    < specialSources>
      <  allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      < notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      < errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors & Warnings" />
    
  
  < exceptionHandling>
    < exceptionPolicies>
      < add name="MyPolicy">
        < exceptionTypes>
          < add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            < exceptionHandlers>
              < add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"          logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library 
Exception Handling"
formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter,
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
priority="0" />
   < /exceptionHandlers>
          
        
      
    
  
  < dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ExampleDatabase" /> 
  < connectionStrings>
    < add name="ExampleDatabase" connectionString="datasource=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated 
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Logging.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
..
    < SafeControls>
      < SafeControl Assembly="System.Web, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
..

      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=2.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration, 
Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, 
Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, 
Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, 
Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.SqlCe, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.SqlCe" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      < SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
..
      
..